# Не работают регулярные выражения в MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, регулярные-выражения, кодировка

Здравствуйте. В БД установлена кодировка utf8. Когда я пишу запрос, используя регулярные выражения, они не работают.

Обычные запросы работают: `SELECT * FROM verb.tableA WHERE rw LIKE 'небо';`

Но когда пишу `SELECT * FROM verb.tableA WHERE rw RLIKE '^неб[оа]$';`, то ничего не выводится. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Обновлено

Как правильно меня поправили в комментариях, выражение у вас правильное, а вот MySql не правильно его обрабатывает. В вашем случае можно такой вариант использовать:

```
'^неб(о|а)$'
```

Все дело в особенности [обработки выражений в MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). Обработка идет побайтово, и поэтому ваш вариант не работает.

### Цитата из документации

> **Warning**
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Comment: *побайтово (и стоило перевести остаток цитаты о том, что многобайтовые символы, вроде кириллических, воспринимаются как несколько символов)

Comment: @D-side, спасибо за поправку

Comment: Можно еще поправку внести - регулярное выражение абсолютно правильное. Неправильна обработка этого выражения движком MySQL. Думаю, что правильно говорить о специфике обработки таких выражений, чем о неправильности исходного выражения.

Comment: @korytoff а по этой же причине не работает оператор . (точка) (то есть любой символ)?

Comment: @Stratocaster а где у вас точка? Вообще точка это любой символ, но в  квадратных скобках насколько я помню это именно точка

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM verb.tableA WHERE rw REGEXP "^неб(a|о)$";
```

Хотя возможно условие через OR будет работать быстрее

```
SELECT * FROM verb.tableA WHERE rw="небо" OR rw="неба";
```

Comment: RLIKE это же синоним REGEXP

Comment: @korytoff, ну кто ж его знал :) Работает запрос и с `REGEXP`, так как регулярка заменена на верную.

Comment: не совсем, в документации ответ есть. Регулярные выражения по битово работают

Comment: @korytoff, что значит не совсем? Вы посмотрите какое регулярное выражение я в ответе написал и какое регулярное выражение у автора вопроса. Вы сами его написали в своем ответе, а теперь говорите что оно не работает?

Comment: у автора то же правильное выражение, проблема в обработке регулярных выражений в мускуле. Если в выражении автора поставить `+` то все будет прекрасно работать, но логика нарушится `^неб[оа]+$`

Comment: @korytoff, при чем тут логика? Мой ответ верен или нет? Если нет, то ваш ответ тоже не верен.

Comment: я говорю про то, что у автора регуряка в принципе то же правильная, просто в мускуле она не правильно обрабатывается, я не утверждал, что ваш ответ не верен

Comment: @korytoff, в таком случае вопрос можно закрыть с формулировкой про опечатку. Автор вопроса просто забыл поставить `+` после закрывающей скобки `]`.

Comment: нет, нельзя, я же сказал что в случае использования `+` нарушается логика. В этом случае найдутся не нужные слова, например небоооо, небааааа, небаоаоаоа и т.п.

Comment: @korytoff, тогда я вас совсем не понимаю. Какие претензии к моему ответу?

Comment: претензии к ваше ответу у меня нету, я лишь ответил на не совсем точное утверждение во втором комментарии. А к вашему ответу я вообще поставил плюс

Comment: @korytoff, спасибо!